# Creating method in ABAP OData service

Tags: odata, abap, sap-gui

I am currently working on an OData service for a SAP Fiori application.
When I try to code the BAPI for inserting notifications into database, it doesn't work & I don't know why. My colleague told me it's because of the missing mandatory parameters but I filled them as well and no result.
Here's the code :

```
METHOD avisset_create_entity.

DATA: ls_data TYPE zcl_zpm_avis_mpc=>ts_avis.

DATA: l_notif        TYPE bapi2080_nothdre-notif_no,
      l_notif_type   TYPE bapi2080-notif_type,
      l_notif_hd_exp TYPE bapi2080_nothdre,
      l_notif_header TYPE bapi2080_nothdri,
      i_return       TYPE TABLE OF bapiret2.

io_data_provider->read_entry_data( IMPORTING es_data = ls_data ).

IF ls_data IS NOT INITIAL.
  l_notif_type = 'S3'.
  l_notif_header-equipment = ls_data-equnr.
  l_notif_header-reportedby = sy-uname.
  l_notif_header-short_text = ls_data-qmtxt.
*      l_notif_header-notif_date = ls_data-qmdat.

  l_notif_header-CODE_GROUP = 'MAINDIAG'.
  l_notif_header-CODING =  'desi'.
*      l_notif_header-CODING =  ls_data-IWERK.
*      FUNCT_LOC

  CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_ALM_NOTIF_CREATE'
    EXPORTING
*         EXTERNAL_NUMBER    =
      notif_type         = l_notif_type
      notifheader        = l_notif_header
*         SENDER             =
*         ORDERID            =
    IMPORTING
      notifheader_export = l_notif_hd_exp
    TABLES
*         notitem            = i_notitemi
*         notifcaus          = i_notcausi
*         notifactv          = i_notactvi
*         notiftask          = i_nottaski
*         notifpartnr        = i_notpartnri
*         longtexts          = i_notfulltxti
*         key_relationships  = i_notkeye
      return             = i_return.

  l_notif = l_notif_hd_exp-notif_no.
  CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_ALM_NOTIF_SAVE'
    EXPORTING
      number = l_notif.

  CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT'
    EXPORTING
      wait = 'X'.
ENDIF.

ENDMETHOD.
```

Comment: Check the messages in `i_return` - anything in there?

Comment: When you say it doesn’t work, what exactly is happening?
How do you test the Bapi?
Can you debug the Bapi?
Do you get an error message?
As mentioned before by user vwegert: Is there any message in i_return ?

Comment: when i debug the program and check the i_return variable, it shows a message saying : indicate the code group code, knowing that i gave it up there as "MAINDIAG".
l_notif is also empty.

Comment: Shouldn't you pass something to the TABLES parameters of your BAPI? TABLES parameters can also be used for passing data, not only receiving.

Comment: as far as i know i passed what i needed to pass in the structure "l_notif_header"

Comment: Check again the BAPI... from what I can see TABLES notitem, notifcaus etc. should be passed  at creation of notification (see description of parameters)